# Script para abrir index.html de múltiplas pastas

Tags: linux, loop, url, bash

Como fazer um script em bash que:

- Com base nessa url de exemplo: http://www.exemple.com.br/1/43530/12620/index.html
- Selecione a pasta 12620.
- Abra o index.html dessa pasta em uma aba do Firefox no Kali (Debian)
- Selecione a pasta 12620 acrescente +1, ficando 12621, e abra o index.html dessa pasta em uma nova aba.
- E assim por diante.

Pensei em algo como:

```
FOLDER=12620
for (($FOLDER, $FOLDER =< 12660, $FOLDER++))
  do
    firefox -new-tab http://www.exemple.com/1/43530/.'$FOLDER'./index.html
  done
```

Eu fiz em JavaScript, só queria passar para Bash e abrir no Firefox

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="abrirHTML()">Abrir</button>

<script>
function abrirHTML() {
var folder = 12690;



for (folder = 12690; folder < 12695; folder++) {
    window.open("http://www.exemple.com/1/43530/" + folder + "/index.html");
}
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao **SOpt**. [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/87998/edit) a sua pergunta e mostre-nos o que você já tentou. Também recomendo a leitura de [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Editei @JéfersonBueno

Comment: @Kaka E não funcionou o teu script? Algum erro? Já considerou usar Python para esse script ao invés de BASH?

Comment: Vai abrir 5 abas novas? 12690 até 12695? Isto seria o loop? Eu não entendi porque os valores do javascript ficaram diferente do teu bash, no js você usou 12690 e no bash usou 12660.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo simples de loop com bash seria assim:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 COUNTER=12690
 while [  $COUNTER -lt 12695 ]; do
     firefox -new-tab "http://www.exemple.com/1/43530/${COUNTER}/index.html"
     let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
 done
```

<sub>Fonte e dicas: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Sei que a questão não envolve exatamente Python, mas desde que Python está presente em quase todos os linux, por que não fazer o script nessa linguagem? Bom, aqui está a versão em Python, mas vou postar depois em Bash:

```
import os, sys
import webbrowser
import urllib2 as net
from urllib2 import HTTPError

FOLDER   = 12620
BASE_URL = 'http://localhost/folders'
BASENAME = 'index.html'

while True:
    try:
        url = "{}/{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, FOLDER, BASENAME)
        net.urlopen(url)
        webbrowser.open(url)
    except HTTPError:    
        break
    FOLDER += 1

sys.exit()
```